# How to clear chart before adding new data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using the Google Visualization API. A chart is generated based on values from an ajax call `function drawchart()`.

The user then inputs values in textboxes and this point is added on the chart also (`function addUserPoint()`). `function addUserPoint2()` is autogenerated and is also added onto the map. The result of adduserpoint and adduserpoint2 have a line between them.

My issue: If the user adds a new point again, the chart adds those values and the previously added points stay on the chart. I want to get rid of the results of adduserpoint and adduserpoint2 before adding a new point. How can I achieve this?

```
var chartData;
var options2;

function addUserPoint() {
if (chartData.getNumberOfColumns() === 2) {
    chartData.addColumn('number', '');
 }
 var aa= $("#wbtotala").text();
 var bb= $("#wbtotalb").text();
  chartData.addRow([
    parseFloat(bb),
    null,
    parseFloat(aa)
  ]);
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);
}

function addUserPoint2(){
if (chartData.getNumberOfColumns() === 2) {
    chartData.addColumn('number', '');
 }
 myLineChart.draw(0,0, options2);
 var aa2 = fweight;
 var bb2= fcg;

  chartData.addRow([
    parseFloat(bb2),
    null,
    parseFloat(aa2)
  ]);
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);
}

function drawchart() {
 document.getElementById('addPoint').addEventListener('click', addUserPoint, false);
 document.getElementById('addPoint').addEventListener('click', addUserPoint2, false);
      chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      chartData.addColumn('number', 'Sli');
      chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

      for (var i = 0; i < chartdatax.length; i++) {
          chartData.addRow([parseFloat(chartdatax[i]), parseFloat(chartdatay[i])]);
          };


       options2 = {
           height: 500,
           hAxis: {
              title: 'AB',
              gridlines: {
                count: 20
            }
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'CD',
              gridlines: {
                count: 15
            }
            },
          chartArea: {top:40, width: "70%", height: "75%"},

          legend: { position: 'none' },
          pointSize: 5
        };

       myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart2'));

        myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below Command.Here data is the DataTable Variable.

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

Answer (score 0):

Set chartData to an empty object in addUserPoint();

`function addUserPoint() {
    charData = {};
    if (chartData.getNumberOfColumns() === 2) {
        ...
    }
}`

This makes sure that anytime you add a new Data, it clears the previous data and you have a fresh new dataset ;)

Comment: Like this? `chartData =""`

Comment: I edited my post. If it is JSON then it should be an empty object

Comment: Oh that makes sense! It gives me an error though `index.js:2485 Uncaught TypeError: chartData.getNumberOfColumns is not a function`

Comment: Maybe I can remove all rows and reload everything? Would that work?

Comment: No problem. Yes I ended up merging `addUserPoint()` and `addUserPoint2()` into one function and then adding `var chartData;` inside the function so it clears before running the rest. Thanks for your help :)